# React to call the fetch method from other file and perform the operation after it success

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a situation where I am calling the http call from inside the actionCreators as shown below

**FetchDataStoreData.js**

```
export const actionCreators = {
deleteUserManagement: (id) => async (dispatch) => {
    const url = `api/UserManagement/${id}`;
    return await fetch(url, { method: 'DELETE', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' } });
  }
  }
```

From the component file I am calling the redux action as shown below

**FetchFile.js**

```
    handleDeleteClick(id) {
            this.props.deleteUserManagement(id);
            // Need to call this.ensureDataFetched(); after the delete is successful from the server side

this.ensureDataFetched(); --> This method should call once the delete is successful
          }
```

Every thing is working fine, but I need to call the this.ensureDataFetched(); method after the response is successful from the server side.

Is there is any generic way to create a http call as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Onw way is you can return the promise from the action and handle it in the component. Like this

**FetchDataStoreData.js**

```
export const actionCreators = {
deleteUserManagement: (id) => (dispatch) => {
    const url = `api/UserManagement/${id}`;
    return fetch(url, { 
                 method: 'DELETE', 
                 headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' } 
                 });
    }
  }
```

And now handle it in the component then call ensureDataFetched function as

**FetchFile.js**

```
handleDeleteClick(id) {
        this.props.deleteUserManagement(id).then(res => {    
        // this will run only deleteUserManagement fetch will complete.
        this.ensureDataFetched();
        }
}
```

May be this will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Change handleDeleteClick to

```
    handleDeleteClick = async (id) => {
        await this.props.deleteUserManagement(id);
        // Need to call this.ensureDataFetched(); after the delete is successful from the server side
        this.ensureDataFetched(); --> This method should call once the delete is successful
          }
```

Comment: Is there any way to create generic Http calls ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the asynchronous function, you can execute it as an [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57087439/11212074), and there are several ways to call the **http**. If you're looking for an `XMLHttpRequest API`,

**Example.js**

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
  if (request.readyState !== 4) {
    return;
  }

  if (request.status === 200) {
    console.log('success', request.responseText);
  } else {
    console.warn('error');
  }
};

request.open('GET', 'https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/');
request.send();
```

If not you're looking for this, you're looking for `WebSocket`.

**Example.js**

```js
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://host.com/path');

ws.onopen = () => {
  // connection opened
  ws.send('something'); // send a message
};

ws.onmessage = (e) => {
  // a message was received
  console.log(e.data);
};

ws.onerror = (e) => {
  // an error occurred
  console.log(e.message);
};

ws.onclose = (e) => {
  // connection closed
  console.log(e.code, e.reason);
};
```

In addition to this, `fisbee` or `axios` can be used.